# Create users for PROFTPD with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, proftpd

I am following the guide to use MySQL to create users in proFTPd. To encrypt passwords, the guide uses the following command:

```
/bin/echo "{md5}"`/bin/echo -n "password" | openssl dgst -binary -md5 | openssl enc -base64`
```

I wander how I would do this in PHP? I have googled this but I can't figure out how to implement this command in PHP. Is it just the MD5 hash of the base64 encoded form of the password?

Comment: There a nice PHP admin implementation for ProFTPD: https://github.com/ChristianBeer/ProFTPd-Admin .I used it, with few changes (Internal security related), in production environment.

Comment: Note MD5 is considered broken for security purposes. You shouldn't ever be using it for passwords nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

Per ProFTPD's [SQL howto FAQ](http://www.proftpd.org/docs/howto/SQL.html#SQLOpenSSLSQLAuthType), you might try using:

```
$password = "{md5}".base64_encode(pack("H*", md5($password)));
```

It's more than just the MD5 hash of the password; it's the base64-encoded form of the MD5 hash, *plus* a prefix which indicates which hash algorithm was used (that's the leading `{md5}` portion of the string).

Hope this helps!